# When Connecting R with RdotNet It says Set Environment Variable 'PATH'

Tags: c#, r, r.net

When I Run the **Warning**

```
RDotNet.NativeLibrary.UnmanagedDll.SetDllDirectory(string) is obsolete Set environment variable 'PATH' instead.
```

I don't know how to do that. how to set variable path please help quickly please.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string dlldir = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64";
            REngine.SetDllDirectory(dlldir);
            REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");

        }


            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet");

            try
            {

                // import csv file
                engine.Evaluate("dataset<-read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep = ',')");

                // retrieve the data frame
                DataFrame dataset = engine.Evaluate("dataset").AsDataFrame();

                for (int i = 0; i < dataset.ColumnCount; ++i)
                {
                    dataGridView1.ColumnCount++;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = dataset.ColumnNames[i];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataset.RowCount; ++i)
                {
                    dataGridView1.RowCount++;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = dataset.RowNames[i];

                    for (int k = 0; k < dataset.ColumnCount; ++k)
                    {
                        dataGridView1[k, i].Value = dataset[i,k];

                    }

                }

            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Equation error.");
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how can you set or edit environment variables in windows, you can use this link:

[Set Environment Variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

PATH includes several addresses, and maybe you should add your `dlldir` address to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an outdated version of R.NET; see the online [documentation](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation) for instruction and sample code on how to install and use the current API (version 1.5.15 or above)